# Check if any UserControl is open

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, user-controls

I've created `UserControl` which extend basic functionality of `ComboBox`.

```
<ComboBox
    x:Name="MultiSelectCombo"  
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
    OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
    Background="#61596f"
>
...
</ComboBox>
```

On page I use 3 controls :

```
<controls:MultiSelectComboBox SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedCategories, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="CategoriesFilter" DefaultText="Category" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories }" Style="{StaticResource FiltersDropDowns}"/>

<controls:MultiSelectComboBox SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedTypes, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="TypesFilter" DefaultText="Type" ItemsSource="{Binding Types, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource FiltersDropDowns}"/>

<controls:MultiSelectComboBox SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedBrandsList, Mode=TwoWay}"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="BrandsFilter" DefaultText="Brand" ItemsSource="{Binding BrandsList}" Style="{StaticResource FiltersDropDowns}"/>
```

I need to change visibility of grid-element `Overlay` on this page when any of comboBoxes is open.

How can I do it? Check every item by name makes too much code.
I tried this, but can't get to child item of my control

```
<Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ComboBoxToggleButton}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
```

where `ComboBoxToggleButton` is button of comboBox which open/close dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use a MultiBinding

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.Visibility>
          <MultiBinding Mode="OneWay" Converter={StaticResource OpenToVisibilityConverter}>
              <Binding ElementName="CategoriesFilter" Path="[a Open property on your UserControl]" />
              <Binding ElementName="TypesFilter" Path="[a Open property on your UserControl]" />
              <Binding ElementName="BrandsFilter" Path="[a Open property on your UserControl]" />TypesFilter
          </MultiBinding>
     </Grid.Visibility>
</Grid>
```

Where OpenToVisibilityConverter is a IMultiValueConverter that check isopen property for each Binded control and return correct Visibility.

Seems no much code to mee.

Comment: I've add Converter `public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
   var collection = (values.Select(System.Convert.ToBoolean));
   var retValue = collection.Aggregate(false, (current, item) => item || current);
   return retValue ? "Visible" : "Collapsed";
  }` . Currently converter seems to work good, but grid is always visible

Comment: You must return  Visibility.Visible or Visibility.Collapsed, not two string.

Comment: Also doen't help... hmmm

Comment: Now is alright. I shoud use enum `Visibility` from `System.Windows` namespace from start. Thanks